# Is aria-expanded only for "click" interaction, or can it be used for "focus" as well?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

Can I use `aria-expanded` on a link element (anchor) with its focus or hover state? So when a user hovers or focuses using a keyboard on the link, the aria-expanded should turn to true, and when hover or focus is removed, it should turn to false.

From what I have read, I could not really find an explicit answer except this link, which says that it should only be used on click, not on focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `aria-expanded`on an element that 'expands' another item such as a fly-out menu or accordion.

It isn't appropriate for showing if something is focused / hovered, it is designed for things that get 'activated' (so a `button` is the normal use case, a link `<a>` is sometimes acceptable if you are using it as a fallback for no JavaScript).

In the example you give it is unclear whether you are exposing a sub-menu on hover or focus and that is why you want to use `aria-expanded`.

**If you aren't** then no don't use `aria-expanded`.

**If you are** I would recommend changing the menu so that when you click it leaves the menu open (as you should do anyway for touch devices) at which point `aria-expanded` is appropriate on click.

In the above example the screen reader would announce on focus the current state as `collapsed` when you first encounter it, so the expected behaviour is to press space or enter and it change the status to `aria-expanded="true"` and announce `expanded` letting the user know they have revealed some additional information (which should be the next tab stop once activated).

You can still have the menu reveal itself to users who are using a mouse on hover.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, this helps. Btw, currently I am displaying sub menu on hover and focus, and also using aria expanded on this, which now seems to be incorrect. I think either i will have to let go of this aria-expanded OR if my UX team agrees, change the interaction so that on focus, a user has to click to expand it, where in then aria expanded will make more sense.

Comment: definitely the way to go, nothing wrong with doing it on hover but on focus I would expect it to be something I interact with, show it with a down arrow. I can't remember the link but the w3 website actually has a great menu example that you could base the functionality on. There is also this example https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html which should give you an idea although the one I am thinking of is better :-P

Answer (score 2):

WCAG 3.2.1 makes it clear that elements cannot change on focus. Keyboard and screen reader users should be allowed to both open and close an element when it receives focus. Regardless of whether it opens on focus or not, aria-expanded is used to alert screen reader users that an element (include anchor tags) will expand with content immediately following that element when it's triggered.

Answer (score 2):

`aria-expanded` indicates whether the element, or another grouping element it controls, is currently expanded or collapsed. [...] this may be applied to page sections to mark expandable and collapsible regions that are flexible for managing content density.

You can apply `aria-expanded` to a link, but if pressing the link triggers an action but does not change browser focus or page location, authors are advised to consider using the button role instead of the link role.

Sources: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-expanded and https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#link